# Hiding and showing parent & child elements on hover/ active using vanilla HTML, Javascript & CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I'm using vanilla HTML, CSS & JS along with Handlebars to create a Mega Menu component. The mega-menu is made up of 3 levels of navigation.

Currently all items are being rendered to the DOM at all times. However, my desired UX is different.

When an L1 is hovered/ active, it should then only show L2's that are a child of that L1. Similarly, an L3 should only be visible when the parent L2 is active/hovered on. My example below shows a fairly small example but when this component grows it could be potentially be made up of 100s of L3's hence the need to "hide/show" elements in this way.

The markup/style:

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('Template').innerHTML);

const data = {
  "desktopL1s": [{
      "label": "Level 1 Heading 1",
      "desktopL2s": [{
          "label": "Level 2 Heading 1",
          "desktopL3s": [{
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image1.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
            },
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image2.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
            },
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image3.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "Level 2 Heading 2",
          "desktopL3s": [{
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image4.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
            },
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image5.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Level 1 Heading 2",
      "desktopL2s": [{
          "label": "Level 2 Heading 1",
          "desktopL3s": [{
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image1.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
            },
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image2.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
            },
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image3.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "Level 2 Heading 2",
          "desktopL3s": [{
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image4.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
            },
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image5.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Level 1 Heading 3",
      "desktopL2s": []
    },
    {
      "label": "Level 1 Heading 4",
      "desktopL2s": []
    },
    {
      "label": "Level 1 Heading 5",
      "desktopL2s": []
    }
  ]
};

const output = template(data);

console.log(output);
document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

```css
.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 24px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-top: 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.content-links {
  width: 25%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding-left: 1.6rem;
}

.content-links ul li {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

figure {
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.content-panel {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 1px solid #eeeee8;
}

.content-square {
  height: 180px;
  width: 208px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="Template" type="text/template">
  <div class="desktop-navigation">
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      {{#each this.desktopL1s}}
      <li id="{{id}}">
        <a href="#">{{label}} </a>
      </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>

    <div class="mega-menu">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="content-links">
          {{#each this.desktopL1s}}
          <ul>
            {{#each this.desktopL2s}}
            <li><a href="#">{{label}}</a></li>
            {{/each}}
          </ul>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
        <div class="content-panel">
          <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
            {{#each this.desktopL1s}} {{#each this.desktopL2s}} {{#each this.desktopL3s}}
            <figure>
              <a href="#"><img class="content-square" src="{{imgSrc}}" alt="{{altText}}" /></a>
              <figcaption>{{caption}}</figcaption>
            </figure>
            {{/each}} {{/each}} {{/each}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

The JSON structure is like so:

```
{
    "desktopL1s": [{
            "label": "Level 1 Heading 1",
            "desktopL2s": [{
                    "label": "Level 2 Heading 1",
                    "desktopL3s": [{
                            "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image1.png",
                            "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image2.png",
                            "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
                        },
                        {
                            "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image3.png",
                            "caption": "Level 3 Child 3"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "Level 2 Heading 2",
                    "desktopL3s": [{
                            "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image4.png",
                            "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image5.png",
                            "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Level 1 Heading 2",
            "desktopL2s": [{
                    "label": "Level 2 Heading 1",
                    "desktopL3s": [{
                            "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image1.png",
                            "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image2.png",
                            "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
                        },
                        {
                            "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image3.png",
                            "caption": "Level 3 Child 3"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "Level 2 Heading 2",
                    "desktopL3s": [{
                            "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image4.png",
                            "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image5.png",
                            "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Level 1 Heading 3",
            "desktopL2s": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Level 1 Heading 4",
            "desktopL2s": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Level 1 Heading 5",
            "desktopL2s": []
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I create relationships between my various navigation levels so that I can achieve this?

Note: In my code, the mega-menu is always visible (for dev purposes) but usually it is only visible on hover.

Comment: Do you have a question? You have only made statements, with no clear question of what you'd like assistance with.